How to add shared-libraries search path for vscode launch
I have a lanch config for gdb.
{
    "name": "arm-testjson",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/out/build/arm-linux/testjson",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [
        {
            "name": "LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
            "value": "$HOEM/.pyenv/versions/3.8.20/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
        }
    ],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/opt/gcc-linaro-13.0.0-2022.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb",
    "miDebuggerServerAddress": "10.1.60.100:2000",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}

I want to cross debug with gdbserver.
Using above config, it with throw a error as 'error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'. My system is Debian12, it does not support python3.8. I had install python3.8 with pyenv, and try to add '$HOEM/.pyenv/versions/3.8.20/lib' to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.But is does work. If copy 'libpython3.8.so.1.0' to '/usr/lib' can make it work. But I still want to know how to add library search path for vscode launch.
